# Google Play Console App Content SMS Permission [App Rejecting]

Tags: android, google-play-console, mobile-application

I am trying to launch my app onto play store and its rejected 5 times actually its using SMS permission->what our app does it take time nd mobile number as input and send SMS to the mobile number after given input time[As alarm receiver class working in background]
Under google play console setting [Polices nd programmes]->App content.. what should i answer to this question?

What functionalities in your app require SMS and call log permissions?

Default SMS handler

Default Phone handler

Default Assistant handler

Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

Enterprise archive, CRM and device management

Caller ID, spam detection and blocking

Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)

Cross-device synchronisation or transfer of SMS or calls

SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)

SMS-based money management

Proxy calls

Services – Operator

Services – OEM

Device automation

Physical safety/emergency alert apps (e.g. senior safety)

Call-based OTP account verification

Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g. Smart Zone Cast service)

Write and Show Call History in Dialler

In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display

Anti-SMS phishing

[App demonstration link->"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg_jnYfGiNI"]

Comment: are you asking for call logs ?  your app needs only sms permissions in order to send sms..

Comment: @KamalNayan asking for only SEND.SMS permission